# Specific users authorization for specific pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I wish to create controller class in asp.net mvc where some of its views will be accessed by specific users and other views will be access by rest of the users .

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Page1()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Page2()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Above code for example Page1() will be accessed by x users and Page2() will be accessed by y users . I want to create a login partial .cshtml code that x users can only see Page1() title , not Page2() and y users can only see Page2() , not Page1() title in the website . How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[Authorize]` action attribute

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

[Authorize(Users="x")]
public ActionResult Page1()
{
    return View();
}
[Authorize(Users="y")]
public ActionResult Page2()
{
    return View();
}
```

}

See below links for authentication and authorization in MVC.

http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part9.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

You can use `SQLRoleProvider` for authorization or have custom authorization.

http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/implementing-custom-membership-provider-and-role-provider-for-authinticating-aspnet-mvc-applications.aspx

Or use custom custom authorize attribute

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357%28v=vs.91%29.aspx

Comment: How can I add multiple users dynamically in this attribute  '[Authorize(Users="y")] ' ? And I have asked about the .cshtml code , not .cs code . I need .cshtml code that will authorize specific users to specific pages .

Comment: Add all users into one Role who access Page 1 and same way for Page 2. In login.cshtml if @User.IsInRole("Page 1 role") display "page 1 title" else if @User.IsInRole("Page 2 role") display "page 2 title"